# in Entity Framework What's the exact value of the IQueryable<T>Include(string path) method?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0

I know I can include some foreign key objects in this way:

```
xx.Include(p=>p.xxId)
```

but I found that there's another overload method has a parameter path.
I want to know what exactly I have to pass the value of the parameter.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigational path.

```
Items.Include(item => item.Category)
Items.Include(item => item.Category.SubCategories)
```

is equivalent to

```
Items.Include("Category");
Items.Include("Category.SubCategories");
```